# Where can I get ispell dictionaries for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, aspell, ispell

How or where, on debian based platforms, I can get `ispell` dictionaries for PostgreSQL (for tsearch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install hunspell-cs`